# Skateboarding vs rollerblading

Tags: sports

I'm 6' tall, 230 lbs, early 30s. I'm totally new to skateboarding or rollerblading. What would be a good sport for me to get into ? My work is 4 miles away, I'm thinking about commuting to work this way. I dont want to fall a lot to get into a sport. Skateboarding looks cool but seems very risky. Rollerblading looks safe but not so cool. Any tips much appreciated.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the Sports StackExchange. But even then, it's still an opinion-based question, which is considered off-topic both here and there.